# Oracle 11gR1: Permission denied error in accessing cdump files

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to access some cdump directories using oracle user but getting Permission Denied error.
I have also checked the owner of the cdump directories is oracle and group is oinstall.
Kindly suggest how should we resolve this issue.

Comment: Just to add more on this, I am trying to access cdmp_YYYYMMDDNNNNNN directories from following location 

/oracle/diag/rdbms/dbname/DBNAME1/trace

Comment: Can you share the complete error message and list the permission set?

Comment: Hi @Mussa, following is the error                                                                 
                     "  -bash: cd: cdmp_20090812145137: Permission denied "

Comment: I am sorry as i am unable to format the errors and other details, please find below the file directory details.....
drw-rw-r-- 2 oracle oinstall 4096 2009-08-12 14:51 cdmp_20090812145137

Comment: Hi, change the permission using chmod command. I have already asked you to list the permission list.

Comment: Hi @Mussa, yes after changing the permission to 777 i am able to access the directory. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mussa, could you please help me understand why are these files get created or a source of the information for detail understanding will also be of great help.

Comment: These files are created by oracle when install it. That directory is where core dumps  are stored. Google it for more information since I am on mobile phone and cannot explain in details.